# Spring Dispatcher Servlet causing issues when trying to load my CSS sytlesheets

Tags: css, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

When I load my JSP page home.jsp I include the stylesheet signIn.css. But something is happening where I get Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for my stylesheet. I think my spring dispatcher servlet is looking for URI /customerPortal/signIn.css when my CSS file is stored at /customerPortal/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/signIn.css (w/o using spring I have no issues). I think its something with getServletMappings where it is cutting off the file location.

My CSS page is in the exact same location as my home.jsp page. I also set up my SpringMvcInitializer class and MvcConfiguration class as I'm using Spring boot. I also have a home controller. I am not using spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml.

```
//MvcConfiguration.java

package Configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import ShoppingCart.Cart;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="Controllers/")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public Cart getCart(){
        return new Cart();
    }
}

//SpringMvcInitializer.java

package Configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override 
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {MvcConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

//home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@include file="header.jsp" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/signIn.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
</body
</html>
```

My jsp and css page are stored in 
/customerPortal/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/home.jsp
/customerPortal/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/signIn.css

But on my eclipse console I get the following:
- DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/customerPortal/signIn.css]
- Did not find handler method for [/signIn.css]
- No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/customerPortal/signIn.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

And on my chrome console browser I get:
GET http://localhost:8035/customerPortal/signIn.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Why is it looking for URI /customerPortal/signIn.css when my CSS file is stored at /customerPortal/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/signIn.css ?

Comment: I suspect that `customerPortal` will be appearing in the URL because of something in your `.jsp` file. Can you share the JSP that's producing the faulty link?

Comment: I  think  / will  catch all requestUri  , you can add this code in your Mvc Configuration .     public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {configurer.enable(); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your information, you can not directly access WEB-INF with URL, Java servlets will not allow it. moreover, do not place resources under WEB-INF

> What should you do now?

Create a folder called, resources under webapp and then create a folder for css (resources/css). then place all css under css folder. and create another folder js and place all JavaScript files there.

then add this method to your MvcConfiguration class.

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
```

now you have your css inside the resources, then access it via

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/signIn.css" />
```

> Solution for your current problem, but not recommend to put static resources under WEB-INF.

change your `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/signIn.css">` code to this

```
<style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/signIn.css"%></style>
```

best of luck...! Happy coding..!

Comment: I add the resources folder under webapp, now my sylesheet link looks like <style><%@include file="/resources/signIn.css"%></style> I also added the resource handler and it is working ! Thanks

Comment: Here is one useful link have a look : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/